# GenericForeignKey in Django Admin Panel

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-templates, django-admin

I'm having issues with displaying `GenericForeignKey` fields in the Django Admin Panel. Additionally, I'm wondering if there's a way to vary the options for the object ID field based on the content type, while ensuring that the selected ID is saved correctly.

Can anyone offer guidance or suggestions on how to accomplish this?

[image: Page screenshot]

I need help improving the wording of the following issue. I've tried creating forms with JavaScript and modifying the admin, but the closest I got was using JavaScript to change the options and display them correctly. However, I had trouble with `self.cleaned_data` not saving the new choices when they varied, and `form.is_valid()` always returned `False` due to validation issues and lost data.

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType
from django.contrib.admin.widgets import ForeignKeyRawIdWidget
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
from django.forms.widgets import ClearableFileInput
from django.forms import ModelForm, ModelChoiceField
from django import forms

from .models import PlaylistContent, Playlist, Image, Video

from django import forms

class PlaylistContentForm(ModelForm):
    object_select = forms.ChoiceField(
        choices=[],
        widget=forms.Select()
    )


    class Meta:
        model = PlaylistContent
        fields = '__all__'
    
    class Media:
       js = ('admin/playlist_content/playlist_content.js',)   

    def update_object_select_choices(self, choices):
        print(choices)
        self.fields['object_select'].choices = choices    

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        global EDIT_DATA_FORM
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        content_type = self.instance.content_type
        if content_type:
            model_class = content_type.model_class()
            choices = [(obj.pk, str(obj.name)) for obj in model_class.objects.all()]
            EDIT_DATA_FORM = choices
            self.fields['object_select'].choices = choices

        else:
            self.fields['object_select'].choices = [] 

    def clean(self):
        playlist_prefix = f'{self.prefix}-playlist'
        playlist = Playlist.objects.get(pk=self.data.get(playlist_prefix))
        
        content_type_prefix = f'{self.prefix}-content_type'
        content_type = self.data.get(content_type_prefix)

        object_select_prefix = f'{self.prefix}-object_select'
        object_select = self.data.get(object_select_prefix)

        if self.cleaned_data['id'] is None:

            if content_type:
                model_class = ContentType.objects.get(pk=content_type).model_class()
                choices = [(obj.pk, str(obj.name)) for obj in model_class.objects.all()]
                self.fields['object_select'].choices = choices

            else:
                self.fields['object_select'].choices = [] 

        #self.cleaned_data.update({'object_select': f'{object_select}'})
        #self.cleaned_data.update({'id': playlist})

        complet_prefix = f'{self.prefix}-object_select'

        object_id = int(self.data[complet_prefix])

        self.cleaned_data['object_id'] = object_id

        return self.cleaned_data
```

```
function update_object_id_choices(contentType) {
    const parts = contentType.id.split("-");
    
    var parts_object_select = contentType.id.split("-")
    parts_object_select[2] = 'object_select'

    var objectSelectContentType = document.getElementById(parts_object_select.join('-'));    

    while (objectSelectContentType.options.length > 0) {
        objectSelectContentType.remove(0);
    }

    const Http = new XMLHttpRequest();
    const url = `http://127.0.0.1:8000/digital_signage/get_object_choices/?content_type_id=${contentType.value}`;
    Http.open("GET", url);
    Http.send();

    Http.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            const response = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
            const objectChoices = response.object_choices;
    
            objectSelectContentType.innerHTML = '<option value="">---------</option>';
            if (objectChoices.length == 0) {
                const errorElement = document.createElement("option");
                errorElement.text = "No hay opciones disponibles";
                objectSelectContentType.appendChild(errorElement);
            } else {
                for (const option of objectChoices) {
                    var optionElement = document.createElement("option");
                    optionElement.value = option.id;
                    optionElement.text = option.name;
                    objectSelectContentType.appendChild(optionElement);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```